# Name space issues

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to input `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` into the header of a message I need to send to a third party.
Or is there a way to remove the `xsi:release` attribute but also keep `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`?

This is my xslt:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$msgtype='Nomination_Document'">
        <xsl:element name="Nomination_Document" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" namespace="{$msgns}">
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:release" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            </xsl:attribute> 
            <xsl:attribute name="release" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <xsl:value-of select="'3'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
```

This is my input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TSMessage xmlns="http://ECG.NOMSInhouse/V1.1.0.0">
    <Header>
        <MsgNumber Revision="1" MsgNo="840711"/>
        <GenerationDate Date="2019-04-16T11:55:22+02:00"/>
        <MsgSender Role="ZSH" Label="" CodeAgency="" ID=""/>
        <MsgReceiver Role="ZSO" Label="" CodeAgency="" ID=""/>
        <MsgType TypeCode="TN"/>
        <Subject Text=""/>
        <MsgPeriod TimeTo="2019-04-18T06:00:00+02:00" TimeFrom="2019-04-17T06:00:00+02:00"/>
        <Contract ContractID=""/>
```

This is what I get now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Nomination_Document 
 xmlns="urn:easeegas.eu:edigas:nominationandmatching:nominationdocument:5:1" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:release="" 
 release="3">
```

I need the header of the message to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Nomination_Document 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="urn:easeegas.eu:edigas:nominationandmatching:nominationdocument:5:1 " release="3">
```

Comment: Um... remove the `<xsl:attribute name="xsi:release">` from your XSLT?

Comment: If I do that xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" is not in the message then

Comment: Not directly relevant: but the XSI namespace is owned by W3C, and it does not include an attribute named `xsi:release`. Adding your own names to someone else's namespace is always bad etiquette and creates potential conflicts; but with the XSI namespace it's asking for trouble because this is a "magic" namespace whose rules and meaning are built into many XML tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `<xsl:element>` and `<xsl:attribute>` *except* when the element/attribute names are dynamically calculated. If they are fixed (like in this case), just write down the elements/attributes directly.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ecg="http://ECG.NOMSInhouse/V1.1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:easeegas.eu:edigas:nominationandmatching:nominationdocument:5:1"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ecg xsi"
>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

    <xsl:template match="ecg:TSMessage[ecg:Header/ecg:MsgType/@TypeCode = 'TN']">
        <Nomination_Document release="3">
            <xsl:comment> ... more processing ... </xsl:comment>
        </Nomination_Document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this XML:

```
<TSMessage xmlns="http://ECG.NOMSInhouse/V1.1.0.0">
    <Header>
        <MsgNumber Revision="1" MsgNo="840711"/>
        <GenerationDate Date="2019-04-16T11:55:22+02:00"/>
        <MsgSender Role="ZSH" Label="" CodeAgency="" ID=""/>
        <MsgReceiver Role="ZSO" Label="" CodeAgency="" ID=""/>
        <MsgType TypeCode="TN"/>
        <Subject Text=""/>
        <MsgPeriod TimeTo="2019-04-18T06:00:00+02:00" TimeFrom="2019-04-17T06:00:00+02:00"/>
        <Contract ContractID=""/>
    </Header>
</TSMessage>
```

produces this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Nomination_Document release="3" xmlns="urn:easeegas.eu:edigas:nominationandmatching:nominationdocument:5:1">
    <!-- ... more processing ... -->
</Nomination_Document>
```

Notes:

- I recommend to prefer multiple `<xsl:template match="something specific">` over a single `<xsl:coose>`, simply because your code will be less deeply nested.
- Declare all namespaces you intend to use at the `<xsl:stylesheet>` level.
- You can pick namespace prefixes freely - I chose `ecg`for the `http://ECG.NOMSInhouse/V1.1.0.0` namespace, you you can pick something you like better.
- Use `exclude-result-prefixes` to prevent unneeded namespace declarations from showing up in the output.

Comment: could you complete the xslt coding to make the message look like what I'm after?

Comment: I like both recomendation about the proper use of literal result elements over  `xsl:element` instruction and the preference of template rules over conditional instructions.

Comment: But I think that the underlying problem of in scope namespace declaration is obfuscated. Declaring the namespace in the `xsl:stylesheet` or in the literal result element `Nomination_Document` has the same effect: if you remove the `xsi` token from the list of `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute then you get the exact exped output.

Comment: @Alejandro Welcome back! I thought you had given up on this website almost 10 years ago. :) I agree, it's irrelevant where the namespace is declared - I just prefer to do it a the top level, so that all the namespaces are managed in one spot.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you! I have some spare time these months, so I came back. I've observe that XSLT 2.0 questions have flourished, not so with XSLT 3.0 (I think maybe beacuse many of the best features are closed source). But answers to XSLT 1.0/XPath 1.0 questions seems to lack deeper understanding of the language and even XML (this might be because scraping and automation also have exploded)

Comment: "Don't use <xsl:element> and <xsl:attribute> except when the element/attribute names are dynamically calculated." When you say dynamically calculated do you mean taken from the input message? E.g i would only use the element if i wanted it to be the generation date?

Comment: @ZakariyaKasu You would use `<xsl:element>` when the **name** of the element you want to output is calculated, i.e. exclusively like this: `<xsl:element name="{$someXpathVariableOrExpression}">`. Any usage like `<xsl:element name="fixedName">` is redundant - you are much better off writing `<fixedName>` directly. Same goes for `<xsl:attribute>`. The only reason those two exist is to support the "calculated name" case.

Comment: @Alejandro I must say, I'm not surveying the question/answer quality in the [xslt] tag at all. I answer when I happen to run into a question (hopefully on above-average level), but the category itself is still a niche closely patrolled by a small handful of high-rep users (I'm not considering myself one of them, as I'm not patrolling). The "fastest gun in the west" syndrome is still strong, and answering XSLT questions still is a thing with an unfavorable economy.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `xsi:release` and add this line `<xsl:namespace name="xsi" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"/>`

An example like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="msgtype" select="'Nomination_Document'" />
<xsl:variable name="msgns" select="'urn:easeegas.eu:edigas:nominationandmatching:nominationdocument:5:1'" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$msgtype='Nomination_Document'">
            <xsl:element name="Nomination_Document" namespace="{$msgns}">
                <xsl:namespace name="xsi" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="release">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'3'" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYiB

Comment: Thank you but when I replace xsi:release with namespace name it says it can't be the child node of an element and I need it to be in that Nomination Document element node

Comment: Have you replaced the whole line ? Don't replace just `xsi:release`. That was used as `xsl:attribute`. I have used `xsl:namespace` rather.